# Mac - Sandboxing - Can't Generate Developer Receipt

Tags: macos, cocoa, sandbox, receipt

Building a Cocoa app using Xcode 4.6, OS X 10.8.2. Sandboxing/Entitlements/Code-signing are enabled.

(It is an update to an existing app on the Mac App Store. iTunes Connect has been updated with the latest version information, and is awaiting Upload of the app.)

I am trying to generate a Developer Receipt, in order to update it for the Mac App Store.

Here's what I've done:

- I built the app in Xcode. In the Finder, I navigate to MyProject/build/MAS/Debug and double-click on the application there.
- In the Console, I see that my app (correctly) can't find a receipt, so it aborts with code 173.
- At this stage, according to Apple's docs, I should either see an iTunes Store authorisation dialog, or a Receipt should be placed in my app's Bundle.  Neither happens.

My Console log shows this:

```
App Log Error: MAS receipt file not found.

com.apple.SecurityServer[15]: Session 100127 created

_softwareupdate[4510]: audit warning: allsoft

_softwareupdate[4511]: audit warning: closefile /var/audit/xxx.xxx

_softwareupdate[4512]: audit warning: soft /var/audit

App Log Error: Exiting (173)

kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(4513) deny mach-lookup com.apple.coresymbolicationd

sandboxd[4513]: ([4502]) MyAppName(4502) deny file-write-data /Users/me/Library/Preferences/com.apple.security.plist
```

I have tried:

- fixing permissions, and disk repair
- restarting the Mac
- restarting in Safe Mode, then restarting
- deleting a (1.31GB !! folder) at /Library/Caches/com.apple.coresymbolicationd

In all events, I keep getting:

```
**kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(4513) deny mach-lookup com.apple.coresymbolicationd**
```

I also intermittently see this:

```
AM mdworker[1375]: Unable to talk to lsboxd
```

Could anyone please advise?